# Explanation of Recursion with Fibonacci Numbers

Tags: ruby, algorithm, recursion, fibonacci

I found a code that determines if a number is a Fibonacci number or not. I was hoping someone might be able to break it down a bit easier.

```
def is_fibonacci?(i, current = 1, before = 0)  
  return true if current == i || i == 0
  return false if current > i
  is_fibonacci?(i, current + before, current)
end

is_fibonacci?(3) # => true
is_fibonacci?(4) # => false
```

I understand that a method calls itself in recursion and that there needs to be a base case, but again, I am having a difficult time visualizing what is going on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks all for the help! Every explanation helped and now it finally makes sense! Thanks again

Comment: Then you should accept an answer and upvote all the other helpful ones as well.

Comment: @user3007294 has the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to visualize it is to step through the computation one method call at a time, suppose we wanted to evalute `is_fibonacci?(8)`, then ruby would set `current = 1, before = 0` since I didn't override the defaults.

Then, since `i` is not 0 or 8, it has to recurse, so the following method calls happen:

```
is_fibonacci?(8, 1, 1)
is_fibonacci?(8, 2, 1)
is_fibonacci?(8, 3, 2)
is_fibonacci?(8, 5, 3)
is_fibonacci?(8, 8, 5)
```

Finally, `is_fibonacci?(8, 8, 5)` can terminate since `i == current (8 == 8)`, so it returns true.

EDIT: Another way to think about this recursion is that your `current` and `before` parameters are 'rebuilding' the fibonacci sequence, if they hit `i`, then the answer is true, but if they go past `i`, it's false.

Answer (score 1):

1. At first it checks whether the `i` (requested number) is equal to a Fibonaccy calculated number, which is passed to `current` variable, or to zero. If it is equal return `true`:

   ```
   return true if current == i || i == 0
   ```
2. At second it checks whether `i` is below to `current` variable. If yes the `i` var will never become a Fibonaccy number, so return `false`:

   ```
   return false if current > i
   ```
3. And at least we calls to calculate the next Fibonaccy number passing next number as a sum of the current and previous numbers to the second argument, and current number as previous to  the third argument for the next step.

   ```
   is_fibonacci?(i, current + before, current)
   ```

Note, that the best way is to expand the tail recursion, as it was shewn in your example, into a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, it is a function that takes `3` arguments.

`i` - The number you are testing to see if it is part of the sequence.

`current` - the current Fibonacci number that you are testing against, defaults to `1` so that you don't need to supply the second argument.

`before` - the Fibonacci number that comes before the `current` number in the sequence, defaults to `0` so that you don't need to supply the third argument.

**EXAMPLE VALUES**

if `current` is `5`, `before` is `3`

if `current` is `8`, `before` is `5`

The function compares the value of `i`, the first argument, and sees if it is equal to either `0`, or the `current` Fibonacci value. If it is equal to `current` or `0`, it is a Fibonacci number (because `0` is the first number in the sequence).

It then looks to see if `current` is larger than `i`. If it is larger, it is not in the sequence. This is because there is no point continuing to check if `4` is in the sequence if `5` is the `current` value.

If neither of those scenarios match, we just call the function again, passing in the value of `i`, finding the next number in the sequence `current + before`, and the value of `before` will be the `current` number in the sequence.

example:

`i` is `15`, `current` is `5`, `before` is `3`. When calling the function again, it will call

```
is_fibonacci?(i, current + before, current)
```

which will evaluate to

```
is_fibonacci?(15, 5 + 3, 5
```

**NOTE**

Ruby has a nice syntax where the `if` can come **after** the thing you want to happen.

```
if a < b
    puts "#{a} is greater than #{b}"
```

is the exact same as

```
puts "#{a} is greater than #{b}" if a < b
```

It just cuts down on the line count, and reads a little more like english.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the call trace if `is_fibonacci?` for two values `10` and `144`. It clearly is calculating the fibonacci number less or equal to the given value, and then comparing it in recursion.

```
  is_fibonacci?(10, current = 1, before = 0)
   is_fibonacci?(10, current = 1, before = 1)
    is_fibonacci?(10, current = 2, before = 1)
     is_fibonacci?(10, current = 3, before = 2)
      is_fibonacci?(10, current = 5, before = 3)
       is_fibonacci?(10, current = 8, before = 5)
        is_fibonacci?(10, current = 13, before = 8)
  is_fibonacci?(144, current = 1, before = 0)
   is_fibonacci?(144, current = 1, before = 1)
    is_fibonacci?(144, current = 2, before = 1)
     is_fibonacci?(144, current = 3, before = 2)
      is_fibonacci?(144, current = 5, before = 3)
       is_fibonacci?(144, current = 8, before = 5)
        is_fibonacci?(144, current = 13, before = 8)
         is_fibonacci?(144, current = 21, before = 13)
          is_fibonacci?(144, current = 34, before = 21)
           is_fibonacci?(144, current = 55, before = 34)
            is_fibonacci?(144, current = 89, before = 55)
             is_fibonacci?(144, current = 144, before = 89)
10 : false ,  144 : true
```

Here is the code that gives this output for first 10 fibonacci numbers:

```
def fib(n)
  if n <= 0 then 1
  else
    fib(n-1) + fib(n - 2)
  end
end


def is_fibonacci?(i, current = 1, before = 0, level=0)  
  puts (" " * level) + "  is_fibonacci?(#{i}, current = #{current}, before = #{before})"
  if current == i || i == 0 then
    return true 
  elsif current > i then
    return false 
  else
    is_fibonacci?(i, current + before, current, level+1)
  end
end

(0..10).each do |i|
  n = fib(i)
  ifib =is_fibonacci?(i)
  nfib = is_fibonacci?(n)
  puts "#{i} : #{ifib} ,  #{n} : #{nfib}"
end
```